# Android AlertDialog crashing app

Tags: android, android-intent, android-asynctask, android-alertdialog

I am trying to show a dialog box when the user inputs invalid data into the search field. The search action including input verification all takes place in an `AsyncTask` in the `Main Activity`. The Dialog creator is in an external class outside the Main activity.

I get a `JSON Array` and check it to see if there are no results. If there are no results then I want to let the user know that via the dialog. This is in my Main which extends `Activity`.

```
try{
            results = jSon.getJSONArray(TAG_RESULTS);


            Log.d("results as string", results.toString());
            String strResults = results.toString();
            if(!strResults.equals("[]")){


                for(int i = 0; i < results.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject r = results.getJSONObject(i);
                    firstID = r.getString(TAG_ID);

                }
            }
            else{

                DialogFragment newFragment = new NoResult();
                newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "noresult");
            }
        }
        catch(JSONException e){
            Log.e("Error", e.toString());
        }
```

here is my `Dialog` creator

```
public class NoResult extends DialogFragment  {

public void customCreate(final Context context){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setMessage(R.string.no_result)
    .setPositiveButton(R.string.back_to_one, DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int d){
               //Try Again
               Intent intent = new Intent(context, Main.class);
               context.startActivity(intent);

    }

});

};


}
```

Even when the result is equal to [] the app runs the rest of code and assembles an invalid api query url. The `logcat` tells me the app crashes on displaying the results activity which is the last step due to error in api query.

This is the link being queried after the dialog fails to show up after finding invalid input: http://api.themoviedb.org/3/person/null/credits?api_key=apikey

**null** should be an *ID number* but it isn't because the search is still being run with invalid data after the if else that's supposed to catch it.

LOGCAT:

```
06-20 02:49:29.091: E/AndroidRuntime(5599): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-20 02:49:29.091: E/AndroidRuntime(5599): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start     activity      ComponentInfo{com.tot.tipofthetongue/com.tot.tipofthetongue.DisplayResultsActivity}:     java.lang.NullPointerException
06-20 02:49:29.091: E/AndroidRuntime(5599):     at     android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
06-20 02:49:29.091: E/AndroidRuntime(5599):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
06-20 02:49:29.091: E/AndroidRuntime(5599):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
06-20 02:49:29.091: E/AndroidRuntime(5599):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
06-20 02:49:29.091: E/AndroidRuntime(5599):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-20 02:49:29.091: E/AndroidRuntime(5599):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-20 02:49:29.091: E/AndroidRuntime(5599):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
06-20 02:49:29.091: E/AndroidRuntime(5599):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-20 02:49:29.091: E/AndroidRuntime(5599):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-20 02:49:29.091: E/AndroidRuntime(5599):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-20 02:49:29.091: E/AndroidRuntime(5599):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-20 02:49:29.091: E/AndroidRuntime(5599):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-20 02:49:29.091: E/AndroidRuntime(5599): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-20 02:49:29.091: E/AndroidRuntime(5599):     at com.tot.tipofthetongue.DisplayResultsActivity.onCreate(DisplayResultsActivity.java:28)
06-20 02:49:29.091: E/AndroidRuntime(5599):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
06-20 02:49:29.091: E/AndroidRuntime(5599):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
06-20 02:49:29.091: E/AndroidRuntime(5599):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
06-20 02:49:29.091: E/AndroidRuntime(5599):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: please add your logcat. the issue is probably because you're using the `applicationContext` instead of the Activity's `Context`

Comment: logcat show the NullPointerException at `06-20 02:49:29.091: E/AndroidRuntime(5599):     at com.tot.tipofthetongue.DisplayResultsActivity.onCreate(DisplayResultsActivity.java:28)`

Comment: You are getting NPE (DisplayResultsActivity.onCreate(DisplayResultsActivity.java:28), So please check the reference value before referring..

Comment: which is your line number 28 in DisplayResultsActivity.java

Answer (score 0):

Here it is

```
 private void showDialog() {

    AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            YourActivity.this);

    SpannableStringBuilder title = new SpannableStringBuilder(
            getString(R.string.log_in));
    title.setSpan(Constants.SPAN, 0, title.length(),
            Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

    SpannableStringBuilder spanMsg = new SpannableStringBuilder(
            getString(R.string.config_manual_sync_msg));
    spanMsg.setSpan(Constants.SPAN, 0, spanMsg.length(),
            Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

    alertBuilder.setTitle(title);
    alertBuilder.setIcon(R.drawable.launcher_icon);
    alertBuilder.setMessage(spanMsg);
    alertBuilder.setPositiveButton("Yes",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Yes clicked");
                    dialog.cancel();
                    Perform action
                }

            });

    alertBuilder.setNegativeButton("No",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                    Log.i(TAG, "canceled");
                }
            });

    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.show();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use `DialogFragment` then you need to override the [onCreateView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onCreateView%28android.view.LayoutInflater,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20android.os.Bundle%29) or [onCreateDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html#onCreateDialog%28android.os.Bundle%29)

here is what documentation says

> Implementations should override this class and implement **onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle)** to supply the content of the dialog. Alternatively, they can override **onCreateDialog(Bundle)** to create an entirely custom dialog, such as an AlertDialog, with its own content.

Please refer the Doc [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html)